# How can I pass a variable of type array

Tags: java

How can I pass a variable of type array as a parameter in an instantiated object

I have this on the **Main.java Class**:

```
String [] itemList;

Magazine magazine1 = new Magazine(nMagazine, itemList[], distributionPrice, pvp);
```

This the **Magazine.java Class**

```
public class Magazine extends Publication {

 private int numberMagazine;
 private String[] itemList;


public Magazine(int numberMagazine, String[] itemList, float distributionPrice, float pvp) {
    super(distributionPrice, pvp);
    

    this.numberMagazin = numberMagazin;
    this.itemList = itemList;

}
```

In the main class when
I instantiate the magazine1 object I can't call the **itemList[]** variable and I don't understand why

Comment: post a [mcve] please

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the braces [] when you reference the array. Instead of `itemList[]` it should be just `itemList` like this:

```
String [] itemList;

Magazine magazine1 = new Magazine(nMagazine, itemList, distributionPrice, pvp);
```